# Start Audio streaming in the background

Tags: objective-c, background, audio-streaming

I'm developing an application that allows to stream a list of audio files that will be played one after the other. I'm using mattgallagher's audiostreamer from [github](https://github.com/mattgallagher).

This works fine when the app is active, but when it goes in the background and one song finished, the next one fails to start.**In other words, the initialization of the audio streamer is not working in the background.**

In my info.plist I have set the "*Required background modes*" to "*App plays audio*" but this is not helping to start a stream when the app is in the background.

Its been like a week now I'm trying to search for a solution, but didn't find any. Can anyone help me solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You application will be stopped as soon as you stop playing the audio file, so the second one does not have a chance to start playing.

Initialise one more audio session, that will play a short silent audio file in a loop. You can keep it as long as you need.
The session should allow mixing the audio, which will have no effect on your audio because the audio file is silent.

```
AudioSessionInitialize(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
AudioSessionSetActive(YES);
UInt32 sessionCategory = kAudioSessionCategory_MediaPlayback;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_AudioCategory, sizeof(sessionCategory), &sessionCategory);

UInt32 allowMixing = true;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers, sizeof(allowMixing), &allowMixing);

NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"silentAudio" ofType:@"m4a"];
NSURL* fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSError* error = nil;
self.beatPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
if (error != nil)
{
    //process the error
}
_beatPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1;
[_beatPlayer play];
```

Stopping the playback will also stop the application threads:

```
[_beatPlayer stop];
```

Comment: Hi @Davyd, thanks for your answer, I'll try it as soon as I get home and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UIBackgroundModes`: [iPhoneOSKeys](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html).

In your `.plist` file:

```
<key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
   <string>audio</string>
</array>
```

*Update:*

Add this to your init code:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

Comment: Hi MikroDel, I have already set the "Required background modes" to "App plays audio". This helps me keep my audio session alive when the app goes into background, but my main problem is that it will not START streaming another song when the first audio file has ended.

Comment: Hi again.I have tried to put this code in multiple places:
- in appdelegate,in applicationDidEnterBackground function:
- in my view controller before calling [streamer start]; 
but still I'm facing the same problem.
Where should I exactly put the code?